# How to select Python listbox data and populate it to specific enty box - pretype

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

So far everything is working correctly, however I am struggling with getting the data below, once highlighted by the mouse and once hitting the select button to populate the correct entry boxes. This may be asking too much.

Listbox display

```
2-12312 Bob Seesaw Active

4-1212 Jim Beene Off
```

So if I highlight the Bob Seesaw row and hit select. The 2-12312 will pretype 'num_input', Bob 'nam_input' and so on. The purpose of this is so I can then type a new assignment and update the database for that entry.  ( I pasted code specific to my initiative.

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql as mdb

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Listbox

def viewroster():
    rosterList.delete(0, "end")

    dbi = mdb.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="user", passwd="pass", db="interactive_db")
    cursor = dbi.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT number, firstname, surname, assign FROM active_roster""")
    rows=cursor.fetchall()
    dbi.close()
    print (rows)
    for results in rows:
     rosterList.insert("end", results)


 #Input Fields

num_input=StringVar()
num_input=Entry(root,textvariable=num_input)
num_input.grid(row=0,column=1)

ass_input=StringVar()
 ass_input=Entry(root,textvariable=ass_input)
ass_input.grid(row=0,column=3)


 nam_input=StringVar()
 nam_input=Entry(root,textvariable=nam_input)
 nam_input.grid(row=1,column=1)

 sur_input=StringVar()
 sur_input=Entry(root,textvariable=sur_input)
 sur_input.grid(row=1,column=3)

 # This is to select mouse highlighted data 
 rosSelButt=Button(root, text="Select", width=12)
 rosSelButt.grid(row=13, column=0)
```

-

```
Number [2-12312]

Firstname    [Bob]  Surname  [Seesaw]  Assign [......] (ready for text)
```

I do not want to loose the capability of typing a name or number as an entry and searching the database.

Comment: example on GitHub [event-listboxselect-get-curselection.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/listbox/event-listboxselect-get-curselection.py)

Comment: I am new to Python and dont quite understand how this pre-populates the entry boxes as per my example. This part is obvious an advance setting and why I am struggling

Comment: when you select element in list then `<<ListboxSelect>>` will execute function in which you have to copy selected data from `Listbox` to `Entries` manually.

Comment: How to I seperate the number and the name and put it in the correct entry box?

Comment: you have string so use slicing, split(), strip() and other string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listbox gives selected element as strin and I have this text formated in columns with

```
'{:10s}|{:15s}|{:10s}'
```

so I can use slicing to get data from correct place, and `strip()` to remove spaces.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def on_selection(event):
    line = event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection())

    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e2.delete(0, 'end')
    e3.delete(0, 'end')

    e1.insert('end', line[:10].strip())
    e2.insert('end', line[11:26].strip())
    e3.insert('end', line[27:].strip())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, font=('monospace', 10), selectbackground='red')
listbox.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')

listbox.insert('end', '{:10s}|{:15s}|{:10s}'.format('2-12312', 'Bob Seesaw', 'Active'))
listbox.insert('end', '{:10s}|{:15s}|{:10s}'.format('4-1212', 'Jim Beene', 'Off'))

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.pack()

e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.pack()

e3 = tk.Entry(root)
e3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Holy thats great - I really appreciate your help

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'  - is the error I get for database values.  I am pulling from three different columns in the Mysql table so it is seeing that.  If I have only one cell or column it works fine but this is not my situation.

Comment: As seen in console  ('2-12312', 'Bob', 'Seesaw', None), ('1-3212', 'Jen', 'Jenny', None) from Mysql SELECT query

Comment: I use `strip()` with single string but you have row with many elements. If you need to strip something then you have to do it with every element separately - ie. `id = row[0].strip()`. But your tuple has data which doesn't need to strip anything.

Comment: duprows = [ '  '.join(row) for row in rows] I have tried adding JOIN but no success - keeps erroring out

Comment: what error ? You have `None` in row so you have to convert it to string (or replace with empty string) before you can `join` elements. But `None` is last element in row so you can use slicing to remove it  `''.join(row[:-1])`.

Comment: or use string formatting and then you can use `"???" if not row[2] else row[2]` to replace `None` - `"{} {} {} {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], "???" if not row[2] else row[2])`

Comment: Yeah none is actually NULL in the database and shouldn't be.  I neglected to populate that column and should have. That column would contain 'available' or 'unavailable' I still get the same result when trying to split the fields based on their columns.  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'  CONSOLE IS NOW  ('2-12312', 'Bob', 'Seesaw', 'Available')

Comment: YOU CAN"T USE STRIP ON TUPLE !!! - strip works only with single string and tuple is not string, it is list with many elements. You have to you index to get element from tuple - ie. `row[0]` - and then you can use `strip` - `item = row[0].strip()`. But your data in tuple doesn't have to be stripped - they looks OK.

Comment: `strip()` is used to remove spaces and tabs from both ends of string. Your data seems not have spaces and tabs in any element.

Comment: Thanks I missed your message "I use strip() with single.."

Comment: I appreciate your help, Furas, I have been off trying to get a better understanding on the options you propose and how to apply them in the proper syntax.  Thanks again.